# Is "UML Class Diagram" available in IntelliJ community edition?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is *UML Class Diagram* feature available in IntelliJ community edition? I only have the community edition, and I have looked every where in the menus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [feature comparison page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) shows that the [UML designer](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/uml_designer.html) is only available in the Ultimate edition.

Answer (score 2):

For Community edition "Code Iris" is available.  I installed it on 2016.1 IntelliJ Community edition.

Comment: After installing the plugin IntelliJ 2018.2 didn't open my projects anymore.